# Why must I call select again in order to selectAll?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some code in d3 (+react) where I have circles already in the DOM and I am trying to add some attributes to them...

The following code works, but it does not work if I just use `s.selectAll()` instead of calling `select()` again in the last block. Why is that?

```
    const s = select(this.node) // select the ref to operate on it with the d3 API
      .attr('width', this.width + margin * 2)
      .attr('height', this.height + margin * 2)
      .append('g') // append a <g> container
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`); // add back in the margins

    s.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis') // set the class for the x axis
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${this.height})`)
      .call(axisBottom(xScale)); // add the axis

    s.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis') // set the class for the y axis
      .call(axisLeft(yScale)); // set the axis

    // the incoming data is an array of numbers, and mapping through it gives the [value, index] which is y and x
    const dataset = data.map((y, x) => [y, x] as [number, number]);
    const color = this.randomColor();

    s.append('path')
      .datum(dataset)
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .style('stroke', color('.2'))
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .style('stroke-width', 3)
      .attr('d', chartLine);

    select(this.node)
      .selectAll('.dot')
      .data(dataset)
      .style('stroke', color('.5'))
      .style('fill', color('.5'))
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`)
      .attr('cx', (_, i) => xScale(i))
      .attr('cy', d => yScale(d[0]))
      .attr('r', 4);
``
```

Comment: The last statement is missing an `.enter().append("circle").attr("class", "dot")`, isn't it?  This shouldn't work with neither `s` nor `select(this.node)`. Besides that, `s` is a selection holding the outer `<g>` container to which the axes and the path are appended to. `select(this.node)` on the other hand is a selection containing the outer node, i.e. probably the SVG itself.

Comment: ok. I think the second part of your answer answers my question. As for your first part, I am manually adding the right amount of circles with react because I want to wrap them in other components